# Is there a way to fix my WooCommerce code and move the category description below products on all devices?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have tried using the code below

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 2 );
function custom_archive_description(){
    if( is_product_category() ) :
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5 );
    endif;
}
```

and it works to PC(big screens) only but on mobile it displays the category description on top and below

it expected the code to move the description below on any device but only did so for the PC version

Comment: This seem to be related to css more than anything else. Post some css and html.